# stylus (css) calculation based on current screen width

Tags: css, stylus

I want to do something like

```
.findcol1 > img
        max-width 1.5em
        max-height 1em
        @media screen and (min-width 700px)
                max-width [1.5 + Math.floor("current_screen_width"/700)]em
                max-height [1 + Math.floor("current_screen_width"/700)]em
```

How can I do this in stylus?

(So max-width should change like - 
`1.5em for width between 0px and 699px
2.5em for width between 700px and 1399px
3.5em for width between 1400px and 2099px, and so on)`

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is a bit too broad for this format, because it essentially asks for a complete solution to be provided.

Comment: I don't completely understand your question, you should put more effort into making it clearer. It is hard for us to help otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 -**

```
.findcol1 > img
        width 1.5em
        height 1em
        @media screen and (min-width 700px) and (max-width 1399px)
                width 2.5em
                height 2em
        @media screen and (min-width 1400px) and (max-width 2099px)
                width 3.5em
                height 3em
```

**Option 2 -** (approximate solution)

```
$emval = calc((700px - 1em) + 1em)
// find number of em's in 700px

.findcol1 > img
        width 1.5em
        height 1em
        @media screen and (min-width 700px)
                width "calc((100% - %s + 1.5em)" % $emval
                // Subtract em's in 700px from em's in current screen size 
                // and add to original width
                height @width/1.5
                // If aspect ratio is not 1.5, we can do 
                // height "calc((100% - %s + 1em)" % $emval
                // Here ^^ 100% will equal 100% height of parent element
                max-width 3em
                max-height 2em
```

`floor()` works only on real numbers, not on variables in Stylus!